# How come I never get an IP address for my Wlan0 interface using VM in Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, router, virtualbox

I hope someone can answer my issue.  I'm running Kali Linux 4.14.0-kali-amd64 (latest) in VM VirualBox v5.1.30.  Host machine is Windows 8.1 and my wireless usb adapter is Panda Wireless N600 Dual Band.  I have the Network setting in VM as Bridged Adapter to my internal wireless card and can successfully ping and execute airodump-ng wlan0 with results.

I never get an IP address for the Wlan0 interface either in ifconfig -a or by running the route -n command and can't figure out why.  I can tell you that I have an all-in-one modem/router unit, not sure if that would be an issue.  Ive posted in text below and x'ed out the mac addresses.  Thanks in advance to anyone who can assist.

```
root@kali2017:~# ifconfig -a
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.0.59  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
    inet6 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    inet6 2601:201:1:4ee0:91d3:4b88:75d3:8e77  prefixlen 64  scopeid 
0x0<global>
    ether xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 58  bytes 8752 (8.5 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 60  bytes 5399 (5.2 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 24  bytes 1432 (1.3 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 24  bytes 1432 (1.3 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether aa:d4:12:6e:e1:45  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@kali2017:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    UseIface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply G-man.  You want the screenshots as text instead?  please advise and thanks.

Comment: Why do you expect `wlan0` should have an IP address? Did you try to connect to a wireless network with it?

Comment: I'm taking a course and the instructor who apparently has the same setup had his wireless lan appear in the routing table.  I'm just trying to learn this stuff.  thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the Virtual Box Extensions Pack from the [downloads page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and install it.
2. Change your bridged adaptor to NAT since it might interfere with the actual USB wireless device.
3. Add the USB wireless adaptor device(check virtual box machine settings) to your Kali Linux guest VM.
4. Setup WiFi on your Kali Linux as usual.
5. Check wlan0